# Amaj chord: Fret buzz on the D string

Tags: guitar

While playing the A chord on my acoustic, I can’t get rid of fret buzz on the D string, no matter how hard I try.
I almost wonder if you guys have found a more parallel angle of the wrist so that the middle finger isn’t forced to fret so far back… then I realize we all have to deal with that thing called the neck.

I feel like taller frets is the only way to prevent buzz while the finger is so far behind the fret.(I can only get about 5/8” close to the fret)

Thoughts?

Comment: Just to confirm: If you play only that string but fretted as you would when playing the chord, the buzz still occurs?

Comment: Exactly what fingering do you use for your A chord? I assumed 123 bottom to top but you mention the middle finger being far back..

Comment: @Aaron yes, if not buzz then a really poor tone

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy yeah I do 234 because my index finger would be even further behind the fret and I’m used to playing other chords in A position using the barre

Comment: I generally play an A with the the entire index finger. This prevents the high E so it can be played with in other ways. One of the points of inversions and voicings is to make it easier to play chords and still get the same color. It's always best to learn multiple fingers per chord. You can play A many different ways such as 123, 234, 345, 111, 122, 133, 144, 233, 244, 344, etc and even with some of those you can change the way fingers distribute on each fret(a sort of back to front or front to back. Some can fill twisted up). It's up to you to experiment.

Comment: @Gupta I've seen people play with one finger but wondered if they were somehow skipping the E string. It makes sense to just fret on the 5th, and sounds nice. I'm curious what fingering you prefer for playing other chords in the A shape barre. I find it hard to do a full bar with finger 1, fret strings 234 with finger 3 and reach the octave on high E with finger 4

Comment: You can play A with the high E with one finger but I rarely do unless I have to(it requires "hyperextending" the finger which just means you have to bend it more and it puts some strain on it). You can play the A at the 5th position if you want but of course the voicing is a little different and you have to barre so. Ultimately, again, you should at least try all fingerings out. I do not find it hard to do a full finger 1 barre or even 2 or 3(except a bit near the nut or close up high... depends if it's acoustic or electric and all that).

Comment: Anything you do enough you will get used. I for the half bar open A and getting the high A I find pretty easy(it's a half of a a G barre form. Basically an A chord G form without the 6th string and using open A for the 5th string). It will be hard to do the way you are playing it and there really is no reason to play it that way unless you have to. Note that there are two ways to play the 234. You can play an A major 7 like shape but move the maj7 up to the root(3rd string A note) or sort ofo the "opposite" with the middle finger being "ahead" of the others(it's a 3 note dim like shape but

Comment: squashed up on to the A chord). Generally speaking if you have too much trouble with some shape either you haven't played it enough or you should find an alternative. If by full barre you mean half bar in the open A using one finger, it should be easy but the hardest part, from what i remember, is that sometimes the strings get in the "joints" of the fingers and so might buzz. Generally you sort of "roll" your finger a little so you it's more of the side of the finger. A lot of these things just take care of themselves by playing a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your neck and frets are ok and the E note on the second fret of the D string doesn’t buzz on its own there are a few options you can try. It sounds like you might have pretty wide fingertips that force your fingers into a diagonal angle when stacked.

You mentioned using your middle finger. The most typical way of playing an A chord is with the 1st finger on the D string, 1,2,3 on D,G,B strings respectively. If you are using 2,3,4 try 1,2,3, the conventional way.

The other option is to finger it low to high 2 1 3 as if you were playing an Amaj7 but with all fingers in the second fret. This places the 2nd finger right up against the D string fret.

Taller frets might allow you to put more down force on the string to make contact with the fret but of course they would all have to be taller, which means a re-fret job or a different guitar. Also you shouldn’t have to have to squeeze excessively to get the notes in a chord to speak properly. Lighter gauge strings might be an alternative solution.

I’m pretty sure at least one of these alternate fingerings will work for you.

Comment: I think I found my answer fretting low to high. This seems to get me no buzz. Thanks. And my strings are probably thicker than is good for me.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, using pinky on 2nd, ring on 3rd and middle on 4th strings leaves enough space behind fret 2 for all finger tips to get close to said fretwire. (Although the combination of pinky, ring and index actually take up a little less space on one fret). Seems like in your case, those tips are wider than normal.

No problem, let's capitalise on that fact! Use *two* of them instead of three! It's entirely possible to let the tips overlap, playing all three strings using two fingers. Which two, is up to you. You may even find you can do it using just one finger, and that turns up a little to allow the top string to sound under it. (It's what a lot of us use for an 'A' shaped barre chord).

There are at least nine different fingerings for playing that open A chord. Try each until at least one of them sounds clean. I'm not going to list each, as I'm sure folk can work out those different combinations...

Comment: Thanks, Tim- I like the idea of this but I think my fingers aren't quite wide enough for that- or my instrument has wider gaps. I find that I have to flatten my finger to fret an adjacent string, which makes the higher E string get muted. I might as well use one finger and fret the high E string on 5th fret. I can't figure out how people let their finger bend backwards in order to allow the high E to sound under a half barre